# How to make Grid component take all space besides AppBar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

As part of a React and Material UI project,

In the main div I have:

```
<AppDrawer />
<AppHeader />
<Grid container align={ "stretch" } direction={ "row" } justify={ "center" }>
  { ...something... }
</Grid>
```

Where `AppDrawer` and `AppHeader` are `Drawer` and `AppBar` components of Material UI.

I'm having a hard time trying to make the `Grid` component take the rest of the page (besides the `AppHeader` component).
I tried using CSS and `height: 100%` the `html`, `body`, and `#root` tags, but that still doesn't work.

Over at the documentation they're using the `align={ "stretch" }` prop, but that doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?